# Read a title in HTML with Python script

Tags: python, html, urllib, beautifulsoup

I have a small problem, I want to read a title in a HTML document, this is working so far, that I get the result of the string. Im using the libraray bs4 BeautifulSoup and urllib.request.

[image: HTML Code]

You can see in the first image that the HTML code has a gap and this gap is even visible in the commandline, but I want only the title.
So how I can remove the HTML codes in the Output?

[image: Command line Output]

Edit:
Here is the Python code you are looking for and which I have used

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs

htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.packtpub.com/packt/offers/free-learning")

htmltext = htmlfile.read()

print(htmltext)


soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, 'html.parser')

print(soup)

f = codecs.open("freebook.html", "w", "utf-8")
f.write(soup.get())

f.close()
```

I hope this code help you

Comment: You are asking how to extract the text from a tag which is at the very basics of using bs4. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Without example code it's hard to give you an exact solution, but you can use `h2.get_text(strip=true)` where `h2` is a variable pointing to the `h2` element yo want to print out.

This is the documentation on `get_text()` - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Share your code and `html` if you need more help

Comment: Hi, yes you are right, I dont have shared the code, I will share it :)

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you have the text content of an h2 tag in a variable, and you want to strip whitespace. So you can use `strip=true` in bs4 or `title = title.strip()`.